# Swift FrameWork working in simulator can't able to compile in Device

Tags: ios, swift, git, cocoapods, podspec

Am created a `Swift FrameWork`. And I created a `Podspec` file for `CocoaPods`.

Using this I integrating my framework using cocoa pods. Its working fine in `Simulator` but I try to run it in `iPhone Device` I can't able to access the framework. Its show the error `use of unresolved identifier`.

> My Podspec file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = "MySDK"
s.version          = "0.1.0"
s.summary          = "My framework Summary"
s.license          = { :type => "MIT", :text=> <<-LICENSE
MIT License
}
s.homepage         = "https://www.mysdk.com/home"
s.author           = { “Me” => “me@me.com” }
s.source           = { :git => "https://git.com/mysdk.git", :tag => s.version }
s.platform         = :ios, '9.0'
s.requires_arc     = true

s.source_files     = "iOS/**/*.{swift}"
s.public_header_files = "iOS/MySDK.framework/Headers/MySDK-Swift.h,native/MySDK.framework/Headers/MySDK.h"
s.preserve_paths   = "iOS/MySDK.framework"
s.vendored_frameworks = "iOS/MySDK.framework"

s.frameworks       = 'UIKit'
s.dependency 'RxSwift',    '3.0'
s.dependency 'RxCocoa',    '3.0'
s.dependency 'RxDataSources', '1.0'
end
```

Anybody guide me a solution compile my framework in Device

Comment: Have you tried to remove the app from the app if you have it installed already and then try to clean the project and rebuild it?

Comment: I tried ... Its not working